# Cannot copy data from HDD to USB

Tags: windows-8.1, file-transfer

I am planning to reinstall my `Windows 8.1` and install `Windows 10`. 
Two days ago I start copy data from my `C:\` drive an unfortunately it takes a lot of time and sometimes it stuck in 30% and it needs more then `10 hours` to copy. 
I decide to stop copy data and create .ISO image of ``C:` drive but problem is same. Using `7-zip` it also take a long time to create `.RAR file` but amount of data is not more then `6GB`
Anyone how can guide me and tell me what could be problem with these and how can I make a copy of my C: drive ?

Comment: If an operation where an HDD is involved suddenly becomes very very slow this is usually an indicator of an dieing HDD. If it only happens when the external HDD is involved then most likely it is this HDD. Another potential reason may be defect USB cables forcing the computer to repeat again and again a transmission.

Comment: This is happend only when I try to copy data from `HDD` to `USB`. Howevery, `OS` also working so slowly, I assume that these is cause problem.

Comment: Use a toot like crystaldiskinfo to inspect your HDDs is the have some pre-fail values (e.g. reallocated sector count). If the process always stops at the same point/file stop trying copy it. Buy a new HDD/SSD and replace your system HDD with the new one. Install a fresh Windows 10 and then try to recover as much data as possible from the old HDD.

Comment: How to recovery data ? Is there any free open source software ?

Comment: First copy the files based on their importance. Second what can be copied quickly and stop/leave out all files that take too much time. If you copied the most important files you can try to make an image of the HDD  https://www.howtogeek.com/57442/how-to-backup-and-resurrect-a-dead-or-dying-system-disk-with-clonezilla/

Comment: Thank you for you advice and for help. Let me check what can I do regarding this issues :) Have a nice day :-)